# Ajax won't reload in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

My code works flawlessly in chrome, however the AJAX doesn't reload in IE. Link to [my code](http://hastebin.com/oqabipuxic.xml), suggestions? It loads at first but refuses to reload the page. I'm very stuck and I'd like to use only JavaScript if possible, I am open to use jQuery solution too.

Comment: Please add the code here as well, so it is available, even if the other site goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IE caches your AJAX calls. So, in order to make sure that a call is send, just add a time stamp. You need to update

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php",true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php?t=" + new Date().getTime(),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

You can disable caching globally using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), for example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This appends a timestamp to the querystring when making the request. To turn cache off for a particular [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, set cache: false on it locally, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```

**JavaScript**

I use `new Date().getTime()`, which will avoid collisions unless you have multiple requests happening within the same millisecond.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php?date=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
```